# Getting error 'unknown field hostPath' Kubernetes Elasticsearch using with local volume

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

I am trying to deploy **elastic-search in kubernetes** with local drive volume  but  I get the following error, can you please correct me.
**using ubuntu 16.04
kubernetes v1.11.0
Docker version 17.03.2-ce**
Getting error 'unknown field hostPath' Kubernetes Elasticsearch using with local volume

```
error: error validating "es-d.yaml": error validating data: ValidationError(StatefulSet.spec.template.spec.containers[1]): unknown field "hostPath" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.Container; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

This is the yaml file of the statefulSet:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: es-data
  labels:
    component: elasticsearch
    role: data
spec:
  serviceName: elasticsearch-data
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: elasticsearch
        role: data
    spec:
      initContainers:
      - name: init-sysctl
        image: alpine:3.6
        command:
        - sysctl
        - -w
        - vm.max_map_count=262144
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
      containers:
      - name: es-data
        image: quay.io/pires/docker-elasticsearch-kubernetes:6.3.0
        env:
        - name: NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - name: NODE_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: CLUSTER_NAME
          value: myesdb
        - name: NODE_MASTER
          value: "false"
        - name: NODE_INGEST
          value: "false"
        - name: HTTP_ENABLE
          value: "true"
        - name: ES_JAVA_OPTS
          value: -Xms256m -Xmx256m
        - name: PROCESSORS
          valueFrom:
            resourceFieldRef:
              resource: limits.cpu
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 0.25
          limits:
            cpu: 1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9200
          name: http
        - containerPort: 9300
          name: transport
        livenessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: transport
          initialDelaySeconds: 20
          periodSeconds: 10
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /_cluster/health
            port: http
          initialDelaySeconds: 20
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        volumeMounts:
        - name: storage
          mountPath: /es
        volumes:
      - name: storage
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the wrong structure. `volumes` must be on the same level as `containers`, `initContainers`.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: es-data
  labels:
    component: elasticsearch
    role: data
spec:
  serviceName: elasticsearch-data
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: elasticsearch
        role: data
    spec:
      initContainers:
      - name: init-sysctl
        image: alpine:3.6
        command:
        - sysctl
        - -w
        - vm.max_map_count=262144
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
      containers:
      - name: es-data
        image: quay.io/pires/docker-elasticsearch-kubernetes:6.3.0
        env:
        - name: NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - name: NODE_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: CLUSTER_NAME
          value: myesdb
        - name: NODE_MASTER
          value: "false"
        - name: NODE_INGEST
          value: "false"
        - name: HTTP_ENABLE
          value: "true"
        - name: ES_JAVA_OPTS
          value: -Xms256m -Xmx256m
        - name: PROCESSORS
          valueFrom:
            resourceFieldRef:
              resource: limits.cpu
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 0.25
          limits:
            cpu: 1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9200
          name: http
        - containerPort: 9300
          name: transport
        livenessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: transport
          initialDelaySeconds: 20
          periodSeconds: 10
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /_cluster/health
            port: http
          initialDelaySeconds: 20
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        volumeMounts:
        - name: storage
          mountPath: /es
      volumes:
      - name: storage
```

You can find [example here](https://medium.com/@jmarhee/using-initcontainers-to-pre-populate-volume-data-in-kubernetes-99f628cd4519).

Comment: but r u sure , once the container restart the data will get the same?

Comment: I need elastic-search to be safe every time.

Comment: You need to configure your Persistent Volume. Please see https://akomljen.com/kubernetes-persistent-volumes-with-deployment-and-statefulset/ for details. Also I see that volumeClaimTemplates already configured in source, where your got your yaml from: https://github.com/pires/kubernetes-elasticsearch-cluster/blob/master/stateful/es-data-stateful.yaml

Comment: Inspect both urls I have provided above and configure storage for your needs

Comment: Actually, using `hostPath` for storing any APP's data in the node - is really bad idea

Comment: I have created storageclass and PersistentVolume and mansion  to elastic_search.yaml file , now the pv is listing correctly and storageclass also listing , but statefulsets.app POD is went **CrashLoopBackOff** , yaml file and error details added in below link. [link](https://github.com/SHUFIL/kube/blob/master/kubernets_pod_error), also  i tried with create PVC but that also POD went failed because of this error  **1 node(s) didn't find available persistent volumes to bind, 1 node(s) had taints that the pod didn't tolerate.**

Comment: i have removed readinessProbe: and livenessProbe: from statefulset yaml file, then after its not going to CrashLoopBackOff ,also i can login inside the POD, elasticsearch working there , only getting some error in POD log,  please see this POD [error_log](https://github.com/SHUFIL/kube/blob/master/pod_error_log)

Comment: This may be DNS related issue. See [this topic](https://github.com/pires/docker-elasticsearch-kubernetes/issues/35) with exactly same errors. Also I think its better to start new question on forum. Your initial question has been resolved

Answer (score 1):

Check your format, hostPath is not supposed to be under container part, 'volume' is not in it's position.